# Identify an inductor on a PCB

Tags: inductor, identification

I'm working on some home networking and automation projects, and am trying to reproduce the circuitry in one of my remotes so that I can connect it to a microcontroller without rendering the remote unusable.  The remote circuit has two inductors in it, one of which is a variable (see the pictures below).  I'm not very knowledgable on inductors, so how do I identify the appropriate components to duplicate the circuit?  I know I can use the colors on the fixed inductor (If read it correctly, it's 1.1 µH ± 10%?), but how do I choose the right core to use?  I'm not sure what to do with the variable one, though.

Fixed Inductor:
[image: Inductor 1]

Variable Inductor:
[image: Inductor 2]

Comment: Depends how it's used. If it has significant current in it then something usefully larger of the same inductance is likely to be OK. Odds are it provides an inductive pulse to an LED or is used in a DCDC boost converter. Peak current is probably ~~~= 2 x Ibattery_on /duty cycle. eg if it draws 20 mA when sending and on off ratio is 1:9 then Ipeak DC is perhaps 20 mA x (9+1)/1 x 2 = 400 mA. Perhaps.

Comment: You can't choose the right core because with only pictures to go on, you cannot know what current or voltage is applied to the inductor. It's guesswork unless you can find out more.

Comment: @Andy Voltage is irrelevant to core choice.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Odds are definitely not used in a DC/DC converter.  It's a remote.  It's not going to double it's cost, become an FCC EMI nightmare, and slowly drain it's batteries even when not in use by using a boost converter.  It will just use 2 1.5V cells or a 3V coin cell like every other remote ever made.  The inductor is part of an LC tank circuit, based on the images, this remote is an RF one of some sort.

Comment: @metacollin don't be simple/naive/petty, voltage is the 1st derivative of current (in an inductor) so clearly saturation point can be calculated knowing only the voltage waveform and the inductance.

Comment: @metacollin I think you are ikely right re non-power use - the adjacent 2sc9018 is an especially wimpy transistor (50 mA rated) targeted at RF & small signal use. It may be part of a custom 38 kHz or other decoding scheme. | I used DCDC boost converter perhaps more loosely than some might - I had in mind the provision of a turn on pulse to the transistor, current ramp in inductor and then inductor ringing on pulse termination to provide an energy pulse to LED. This can allow good results at very low battery voltages. | I'm 'rather acquainted' with the properties of DC DC convertres, EMC, ....

Comment: @metacollin .... quiescent current (zero as described above) and more. | | This is NOT the internet , despite misleading appearances and the manner in which you reached this site, and the general internet 'rules' of open battle and rudeness are not applicable.  Rules of behaviour are that politeness actually matters - notwithstanding that we all - including me - don't always manage :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first inductor has red lines, not brown, so it is a 2.2µH valued inductor with 10% tolerance.  10% tolerance components can't be valued with 1.1 - it's just the high half of a 1's tolerance, or the low half of a 1.2's tolerance. You can have a 10% tolerance 2.2 valued component though. See [E Series.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preferred_number#E_series)

Anyway, inductors not magical or unicorns, you just buy them like any other component.  You don't wrap artisan capacitors from scratch or make oven baked carbon resistors, right? Well...ok, that could be fun.  But winding inductors can be two things: terrible, or really terrible.

[Inductors, inductors everywhere!](http://www.mouser.com/Passive-Components/Inductors/Fixed-Inductors/_/N-wpczZscv7?P=1z0wrhfZ1z0x6d8Z1z0z819&Ns=Pricing)

I think the 16¢ is my favorite.  Entirely because it's 16¢. The 'saturation' current is the maximum current you can put through it.  Size to your needs.  More turns around a core increases inductance (in fact, inductance is proportional to the square of the turns) but at the same time decreasing the saturation current.  For this reason, inductors of a fixed size will see a drop in saturation currents as their inductance values go up, and vise versa.  2.2uH is nothing, so even tiny cores happily exceed the current rating of the wire around the core.  There is not a 'wrong' choice amongst the entire list of inductors I linked (I think).
The second inductor is a capacitor.  It's a Murata TZ03 trimmer capacitor.  They don't say what their value is, but its probably a dozen picofarads or so.  It is used to tune the remote to the right frequency.  There are a very small number of possible trimming ranges, you'll either need to buy a meter that can measure capacitance with picofarad resolution...or trial and error.  Try a 4-60pf trimmer or thereabouts, the value is almost certainly going to be somewhere in that range.  If its not, Murata only makes them up to 220pF. Not to many possibilities.

Good luck!

**Update:** Thanks to [Respawned Fluff](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/197005/identify-an-inductor-on-a-pcb/197016?noredirect=1#comment411289_197016) and his very helpful comment, I think it's same to assume the trimmer capacitor has a range of 2pF to 6pF. I didn't realize the TZ03 type trimmers are handily color coded based on their value.  Looking at the data sheet, blue means it's range is 2pF to 6pF.  This is the same across their entire TZ0X line it looks like, so it's probably a pretty safe bet.

[Murata's Datasheet](http://www.murata.com/~/media/webrenewal/support/library/catalog/products/capacitor/trimmer/t13e.ashx)

Comment: According to [this](http://www.py2bbs.qsl.br/projetos/capacitores/mini_trimmer_murata.gif) the TZ03 cases are color coded based on their range, which might help narrow it down a little (assuming it's an original and that info is correct).

Comment: Much better - +1. | I'm pretty sure that a few of the inductors I've met along the way WERE Unicorns, or, failing that, [**Boojum-Snarks**](http://www.poetryfoundation.org/poem/173165). But, probably not in this case.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  Sorry for the long delay in marking this as answered.